# Which is faster in python, looking up a dictionary by key or a list by index?

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary

Since python lists aren't implemented as arrays, if for some large N we have:

```
dic = { 0: 'val0', ................................, N: 'valN' }
lst = ['val0', ......................................., 'valN' ]
```

for   0 <= X <= N ,which is faster?

```
A) res = dic[X]
B) res = lst[X]
```

Thanks

Comment: Your can use `timeit` to get the answers to all your performance questions...

Comment: Python lists _are_ implemented as "arrays" in the sense you probably mean.  `somelist[i]` takes time independent of `i` - no searching of any kind is done.

Comment: Thanks @TimPeters, that was the answer I was looking for

Comment: If I recall correctly, indexing a list is little bit faster, but not much. Which is surprising because hash function is never computed when indexing a list, but those were the results that I saw.

Comment: @Akavall, `hash` for ints is trivial. Try it :)

Comment: @JohnLaRooy, I don't know what hash function Python used for ints, do you know? I would guess it might be something like FNV, it is fairly simple, but it is more work the just looking up an address.

Comment: @Akavall, simpler even. It's just the identity function for ints that are small enough.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy, Interesting. That would certainly explain the similar performance results between indexing a list and look up in dict. Thank You.

Comment: Compare `List` and `Dict` performance ? Isn't same type, another things you can't search a dict_key (variable dict)  on real time process!

Answer (score 2):

You can run a [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) test like this:

```
d={0: 'val0', 1: 'val1', 2: 'val2', 3: 'val3', 4: 'val4', 5: 'val5', 6: 'val6', 7: 'val7', 8: 'val8', 9: 'val9', 10: 'val10'}
l=['val0', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6', 'val7', 'val8', 'val9', 'val10']

import timeit

print(timeit.timeit("""for i in range(11):
    d[i]""", globals=globals()))

print(timeit.timeit("""for i in range(11):
    l[i]""", globals=globals()))
```

The result is as followed:

```
1.003921410003386
0.9669559969988768
```

With list indexing being a slightly faster.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/HxjO)

The result will remain parallel with increase of N, here's 1000 N:

```
d={i:"val%i"%i for i in range(1000)}
l=['val%i'%i for i in range(1000)]

import timeit

print(timeit.timeit("""for i in range(1000):
    d[i]""", number = 10000, globals=globals()))

print(timeit.timeit("""for i in range(1000):
    l[i]""", number = 10000, globals=globals()))
```

With result being:

```
0.7665060800063657
0.5568666460021632
```

List index is still faster.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/Hxjn)

Comment: For the previous comment saying 11 N is not large enough, I added an example for 1000 N